# How to randomly sample without replacement in R and avoid error ! `size` must be less than or equal to (size of data)?

Tags: r

I need to randomly sample 5% of rows that meet specific conditions *without* replacement. If there are 4 rows or fewer, then I wish to simply skip and move on to the next.

When I run the code below, I get the error message:

```
Error in `sample_n()`:
! Can't compute indices.
ℹ In group 1: `child_id = 112`.
Caused by error:
! `size` must be less than or equal to 159 (size of data).
ℹ set `replace = TRUE` to use sampling with replacement.
```

I expected that I would get a table with the rows that had been randomly selected for each child_id, where if there were not a minimum of 5 rows for a given combination, no rows would be selected, but if there were 5 rows or more, 5% of rows would be randomly selected without replacement.

```
 set.seed(123)
 random_all_speakers_10 <- data.frame()
 speakers <- c("Mom", "Dad", "Other", "Multiple")
 languages <- c("Fr", "Eng")
 
 for (speaker in speakers) {
     for (lang in languages) {
        filtered_data <- data_10_coded_collapsed %>%
            filter(spkr == speaker, lang == lang)
         if (nrow(filtered_data) > 4) {
             num_to_sample <- max(1, round(nrow(filtered_data) * 0.05))
             
             if (num_to_sample >= nrow(filtered_data)) {
                 sampled_data <- filtered_data
             } else {
                 sampled_data <- filtered_data %>%
                     group_by(child_id) %>%
                     sample_n(size = num_to_sample, replace = FALSE)
             }
             random_all_speakers_10 <- bind_rows(random_all_speakers_10, sampled_data)
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't have your data, but this should be possible with `filter` and `slice_sample`.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42) # to get the same sample output for demo purposes
mtcars |>
  filter(n() > 6, .by = gear) |>
  slice_sample(prop = 0.3, by = gear)

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

What's happening here? First, I exclude groups (by gear) with 6 or fewer observations, akin to your first requirement.  Bye-bye five gears:

```
mtcars |>
  count(gear)

  gear  n
1    3 15
2    4 12
3    5  5
```

Then, I sample for 30% of each. From `?slice_sample`, prop will be rounded towards zero to generate an integer number of rows. So for 3 gears, 15 * 0.3 = 4.5 and four lines without replacement are output. For 4 gears, 12 * 0.3 = 3.6 so three lines without replacement are output.